# Como puedo hacer que de una url dependiendo la variable

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentando que este php, redireccione dependiendo de la variable $to que tenga el include, ya intente cambiar preg_match por array pero solo me lanza error 500, que podria ser y como podria hacer que funcione, gracias.

```
<?php
include('url.php');
$urls = preg_match(
'https://www.',.rawurlencode($to).,);
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
header("Location: $url"); ;
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. No me ha quedado muy claro tu pregunta, puedes [edit] para añadir más información de cual es el resultado que quieres obtener. También te invito a que pases por el [tour] y mires esta página [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
$url = 'https://www.' . $to;
```

Es una [concatenación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Gracias,me funciono bro !

Comment: @OscarDavid recuerda que debes indicar cual es respuesta que soluciona tu problema

Comment: @OscarDavid para eso estamos. Y no uses las respuestas para añadir detalles, para eso puedes editar la pregunta. Te invito a que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]

Comment: otra consulta amigo, trato de que enliste una subcarpeta pero me tira error 

$url = "https://www.".$to;"/demo"
como podria hacer para que funcione

Comment: Te falta colocar el punto de la concatenación, tanto si quieres agregar a la izquiera o a la derecha debes colocar el punto para que el lenguaje sepa que debe unir esas dos cadenas. Además quitarle el punto y coma a la variable si vas a concatenar algo más

Comment: De nuevo gracias, soy un noob ! gracias master